# SC_THREAD's wait() statement does not block OS thread

Tags: multithreading, time, wait, systemc

I was having some issue synchronizing threads in my larger program and noticed that some of my wait statements were never returning so I decided to just write a simple thread to test the function of wait and noticed that its getting completely ignored at the `SC_SEC` level. Here's the example I am running:

```
void Transmit::Tx(){
    time_t t1, t2;
    while (1){
        t1 = time(NULL);
        wait(10, SC_SEC);
        t2 = time(NULL);
        cout << t2 - t1 << endl;
    }
}
```

My thread is free running and what i expect is the thread to halt for 10 seconds and resume and the printout should be 10 everytime, but i see 0 and its not printing every 10 seconds, its printing like its ignoring my wait statement. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I am following [this](http://www.asic-world.com/systemc/systemc_time5.html) for my understanding of wait but I don't see what the issue is.

Likewise, when I tried testing with 2 threads which one writes data to a fifo, waits some time, and the other reads the data from the fifo and waits some time, I noticed that the threads never returned from the wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to model a Hardware design using SystemC or trying to use SystemC for software modelling?
It seems you have mixed up the contexts.

SystemC is used primarily to modelling Hardware Design (similar to VHDL and Verilog).

The timing notion you observe in SystemC context does not relate to the real-world time at all.

Of course you will always observe near zero-time execution time when are switching threads in SystemC, as it just switches context of execution to other threads and the SystemC kernel just synchronizes the **Virtual Time**(i.e. simulation time) to model time(virtual time) based event in the SystemC kernel.

Comment: But isnt the purpose of wait(double, sc_time_unit) to halt the thread execution for that specified period of time? That's what i dont understand. Im using systemc for high-level system modeling. I dont have any specifications for hardware nor software, but just a basic system functionality.

Comment: And if i have 1 thread, then there is no thread to switch too. Does that mean the wait statement is ignored? Does that also imply only one thread can be running at a given time?

Comment: wait halt the thread execution only for the specified **virtual time** if provided. Also as per the implementation of OSCI SystemC you already have one thread of execution i.e. the SystemC kernel iteself and all SC_METHOD's run in the context of the SystemC kernel thread while SC_THREAD's are mapped to either user-space threads or system threads depending on the OSCI SystemC kernel configuration.

Comment: So why doesnt my thread halt for 10 seconds in my code since im providing it a time unit and value?

Comment: kindly look at my comment in the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142002/discussion-between-ameyavs-and-javia1492